# The audio disappears from 2/3 of the video after speeding up with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

I have tried to speed up a video file (with the audio stream) 8 times with ffmpeg using the script below. All works well that from a 50 hour video I get a 7-hour video with the audio sped up also, yet in the resulting file the audio lasts for just over 2 hours and silences after that, i.e. there video without audio.

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=0.5*PTS,setpts=0.5*PTS,setpts=0.5*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=2.0,atempo=2.0,atempo=2.0[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" video_x8.mp4
```

EDIT:
video.mp4 file
[image]

video_x8.mp4 file (naming is different for the clear picture)
[image]

EDIT 1.
Here are the full 100MB logs. https://gofile.io/?c=L0Au2e

EDIT 2: Thank you Gyan. But could you please help me write it in 1 command so that it works in 1 go? [image]

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: I am not sure which full log you are referring too. The file took about 5 hours to encode and I did not save the full log. I can try and re-encode it and save the log... Could it be that the problem comes from the fact that the file is too big - about 13gb?

Comment: I redid that. Here is a massive txt of the logs. https://gofile.io/?c=L0Au2e

Comment: The sound breaks off at about 1:58:22.

Comment: Try `ffmpeg -vn -i video.mp4 -an -i merged_x8.mp4 -af "atempo=8.0,asetpts=N/SR/TB" -c:v copy new_x8.mp4`

Comment: Thank you, Gyan. It is working. Could you please help me write it so that it works in 1 go from the beginning? I am not sure why the audio filter doesn't apply properly in my command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the atempo (whether due to the chaining or otherwise), is not updating timestamps correctly, so the remedy is to insert asetpts afterwards.

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf "setpts=0.125*PTS" -af "atempo=8.0,asetpts=N/SR/TB" video_x8.mp4
```

Comment: Thank you! Besides, do you recommend to split the filter with -vf and -af instead of using the complex one? Or is it simply a preference matter?

Comment: If you're not mixing streams, it doesn't matter.